# Excel VBA Range variables and Autofill

Tags: excel, variables, range, autofill, vba

I'm adding columns to the end of the table. First headings and then formulas in the column underneath. Then I want to Autofill the formulas for the whole list. I believe the variable declaration is the problem. I keep on getting an error at the Autofill section at the bottom.

```
Dim LastCol As Long, lastrow As Long
Dim OOSCol As Long, LCell As Long
Dim LRange As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Application.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet    

With ws
    .Name = "Summary"
    LastCol = .Cells(51, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    .Cells(51, LastCol + 1).Value = "OOS NO SOO"
    .Cells(52, LastCol + 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF((RC[-21]=4)*AND(RC[-20]=0)*AND(RC[-19]=0)*AND(RC[-3]=""Roster"")*AND(RC[-4]=""Listed""),1,"""")"
    .Cells(51, LastCol + 2).Value = "OOS SOO"
    .Cells(52, LastCol + 2).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF((RC[-22]=4)*AND(RC[-21]>0)*AND(RC[-20]>0)*AND(RC[-4]=""Roster"")*AND(RC[-5]=""Listed""),1,"""")"
    .Cells(51, LastCol + 3).Value = "SOH NO SOO"
    .Cells(52, LastCol + 3).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF((RC[-23]=4)*AND(RC[-22]>0)*AND(RC[-21]=0)*AND(RC[-5]=""Roster"")*AND(RC[-6]=""Listed""),1,"""")"
    .Cells(51, LastCol + 4).Value = "Negative Stock"
    .Cells(52, LastCol + 4).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF((RC[-24]=4)*AND(RC[-23]<0)*AND(RC[-6]=""Roster"")*AND(RC[-7]=""Listed""),1,"""")"
    .Cells(51, LastCol + 5).Value = "Overstock"
    .Cells(52, LastCol + 5).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF((RC[-25]=4)*AND(RC[-21]>14)*AND(RC[-7]=""Roster"")*AND(RC[-8]=""Listed""),1,"""")"
    .Cells(51, LastCol + 6).Value = "Dormant Stock"
    .Cells(52, LastCol + 6).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF((RC[-26]=4)*AND(RC[-25]>0)*AND(RC[-24]>10)*AND(RC[-8]=""Roster"")*AND(RC[-9]=""Listed""),1,"""")"
    .Cells(51, LastCol + 7).Value = "Outdated Stock Counts"
    .Cells(52, LastCol + 7).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF((RC[-27]=4)*AND(RC[-26]<>0)*AND(RC[-17]>30)*AND(RC[-9]=""Roster"")*AND(RC[-10]=""Listed""),1,"""")"
    .Cells(51, LastCol + 8).Value = "Total Issues"
    .Cells(52, LastCol + 8).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(RC[-7]:RC[-1])*AND(RC[-10]=""Roster"")*AND(RC[-11]=""Listed"")"
    .Range("A51", Cells(51, Columns.Count).End(xlToRight)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 32, 96)
    .Range("A51", Cells(51, Columns.Count).End(xlToRight)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Font.Color = vbWhite

End With

With ws
    LastCol = .Cells(51, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    OOSCol = .Cells(52, LastCol - 8)
    lastrow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    LCell = .Cells(lastrow, LastCol)
End With

LRange = Range(OOSCol, LCell).Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(OOSCol, LCell)
```

Comment: What's the error you get?

Comment: `Range` does not accept two numeric parameters.  Were `OOSCol` and `LCell` meant to be `Range` objects rather than `Long` numeric values?  Nor can you assign a `Range` to be the result of a `Select` (`Select` does not return an object) but, if you could, you would need to say `Set LRange = ...`. (And, I never use `AutoFill`, but doing an AutoFill with the destination being the same as the original selection seems strange.  [But I have seen stranger things in Excel, so maybe that is how you do it.])

Comment: It was fixed with the following code:    Cells(52, LastCol + 1).Resize(1, 8).AutoFill _
    Destination:=Range(Cells(52, LastCol + 1), Cells(lastrow, LastCol + 8)). Thanks for the replies

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it with the following code with help from a different site. See the last line of code. That's what worked.

```
Dim LastCol As Long, lastrow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Application.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet

With ws
    .Name = "Summary"
    LastCol = .Cells(51, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    .Cells(51, LastCol + 1).Value = "OOS NO SOO"
    .Cells(52, LastCol + 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF((RC[-21]=4)*AND(RC[-20]=0)*AND(RC[-19]=0)*AND(RC[-3]=""Roster"")*AND(RC[-4]=""Listed""),1,"""")"
    .Cells(51, LastCol + 2).Value = "OOS SOO"
    .Cells(52, LastCol + 2).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF((RC[-22]=4)*AND(RC[-21]>0)*AND(RC[-20]>0)*AND(RC[-4]=""Roster"")*AND(RC[-5]=""Listed""),1,"""")"
    .Cells(51, LastCol + 3).Value = "SOH NO SOO"
    .Cells(52, LastCol + 3).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF((RC[-23]=4)*AND(RC[-22]>0)*AND(RC[-21]=0)*AND(RC[-5]=""Roster"")*AND(RC[-6]=""Listed""),1,"""")"
    .Cells(51, LastCol + 4).Value = "Negative Stock"
    .Cells(52, LastCol + 4).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF((RC[-24]=4)*AND(RC[-23]<0)*AND(RC[-6]=""Roster"")*AND(RC[-7]=""Listed""),1,"""")"
    .Cells(51, LastCol + 5).Value = "Overstock"
    .Cells(52, LastCol + 5).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF((RC[-25]=4)*AND(RC[-21]>14)*AND(RC[-7]=""Roster"")*AND(RC[-8]=""Listed""),1,"""")"
    .Cells(51, LastCol + 6).Value = "Dormant Stock"
    .Cells(52, LastCol + 6).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF((RC[-26]=4)*AND(RC[-25]>0)*AND(RC[-24]>10)*AND(RC[-8]=""Roster"")*AND(RC[-9]=""Listed""),1,"""")"
    .Cells(51, LastCol + 7).Value = "Outdated Stock Counts"
    .Cells(52, LastCol + 7).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF((RC[-27]=4)*AND(RC[-26]<>0)*AND(RC[-17]>30)*AND(RC[-9]=""Roster"")*AND(RC[-10]=""Listed""),1,"""")"
    .Cells(51, LastCol + 8).Value = "Total Issues"
    .Cells(52, LastCol + 8).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(RC[-7]:RC[-1])*AND(RC[-10]=""Roster"")*AND(RC[-11]=""Listed"")"
    .Range("A51", Cells(51, Columns.Count).End(xlToRight)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 32, 96)
    .Range("A51", Cells(51, Columns.Count).End(xlToRight)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Font.Color = vbWhite

End With

With ws
    lastrow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
End With

Cells(52, LastCol + 1).Resize(1, 8).AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(52, LastCol + 1), Cells(lastrow, LastCol + 8))
```